# Kotlin: Expecting ')' error, code not running

Tags: kotlin

I am fairly new to kotlin and below is my code. The result I am expecting should be "Hello Kotlin" but I keep getting an error and am not sure why.

```
 fun sayHello(itemtogreet:String){
        val msg = "Hello" + itemtogreet
        println(msg)
    }
    
    fun main(){
         sayHello(itemtogreet:"Kotlin")
    }
```

Comment: `sayHello(itemtogreet = "Kotlin")`, The single colon `:` operator is only for defining Types (return, or parameter types, or explicit variable types) or Extending/Implementation of Class/Interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a syntax problem, you have two options:

1. removing parameter name

```kotlin
fun sayHello(itemtogreet:String){
  val msg = "Hello" + itemtogreet
  println(msg)
}
    
fun main(){
  sayHello("Kotlin")
}
```

2. Use an explicit parameter name (useful only if you have more than one parameter) :

```kotlin
fun sayHello(itemtogreet:String){
  val msg = "Hello" + itemtogreet
  println(msg)
}
    
fun main(){
  sayHello(itemtogreet = "Kotlin")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also occered to me,But the reason is Kotlin.kt calling Java.class.
Wrong writing:

```
MigrationHelper.updateTableColumn(db, UserDao.class)
```

Right writing:

```
MigrationHelper.updateTableColumn(db = db, daoClass = UserDao::class.java)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
fun sayHello(itemtogreet:String){
    val msg = "Hello" + itemtogreet;
    println(msg)
}

fun main(){
    sayHello(" Kotlin")
}
```